# transform method of pandas can not pass multi methods

Tags: python, pandas

I want to pass 2 methods to `transform` method of pandas as the API says it can pass a list of functions or dict of column names -> functions. I pass a list of functions, but it does not work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'rti':['a','a','b','c','b','c','a'],'ts':[10,10,9,12,9,13,11],'rs':[8,8,22,11,12,11,9]})
df.groupby('rti').transform(['mean','sum'])
```

It shows:"TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

Comment: Which version of pandas?  Perhaps it is a bug?

Comment: the version is 0.23.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, but the functions used must not be aggregation functions such as sum, max or min.

```
>>> df.transform([np.abs, np.sign])
        rs            ts     
  absolute sign absolute sign
0        8    1       10    1
1        8    1       10    1
2       22    1        9    1
3       11    1       12    1
4       12    1        9    1
5       11    1       13    1
6        9    1       11    1
```

Refer to the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#transform-api).  Note that the `transform` method for `groupby` objects accepts only a function (not a list of functions which is for the dataframe transform method).

Per the doc string of the `tranform` method of `groupby` objects:

> Signature: gb.transform(func, *args, **kwargs)
>
> Docstring:
>   Call function producing a like-indexed DataFrame on each group and
>   return a DataFrame having the same indexes as the original object
>   filled with the transformed values
>
> ### Parameters
>
> f : function
>       Function to apply to each group
>
> ### Notes
>
> Each group is endowed the attribute 'name' in case you need to know
>   which group you are working on.
>
> The current implementation imposes three requirements on f:
>
> - f must return a value that either has the same shape as the input
>     subframe or can be broadcast to the shape of the input subframe.
>     For example, f returns a scalar it will be broadcast to have the
>     same shape as the input subframe.
> - if this is a DataFrame, f must support application column-by-column
>     in the subframe. If f also supports application to the entire subframe,
>     then a fast path is used starting from the second chunk.
> - f must not mutate groups. Mutation is not supported and may
>     produce unexpected results.

Comment: I try this before , would you like test after `groupby``df.groupby('rti').transform([np.abs, np.sign])`

Comment: I think OP is after the transform method on .DataFrameGroupBy objects, not on DataFrames.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `transform` do not accept list of function , Open issue in [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17309)

```
df.groupby('rti').agg(['mean','sum']).reindex(df.rti)
Out[12]: 
            rs             ts    
          mean sum       mean sum
rti                              
a     8.333333  25  10.333333  31
a     8.333333  25  10.333333  31
b    17.000000  34   9.000000  18
c    11.000000  22  12.500000  25
b    17.000000  34   9.000000  18
c    11.000000  22  12.500000  25
a     8.333333  25  10.333333  31
```